# View text files of ROS logs in color

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes we save our ROS logs as text files and view them later when we need them. However, it can be difficult to parse everything when it's not in color. Is there any built-in ROS solution for view ROS log text files in the normal stdout color?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328793/view-text-files-of-ros-logs-in-color/) by [jwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38683/jwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there any built-in ROS solution for view ROS log text files in the normal stdout color?

No, there isn't afaik.

And I would argue that is also not needed or desirable: the log files are essentially just text files with [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) embedded in the log lines. So any tool capable of parsing such codes should be able to read these log files, removing the need to create something ROS-specific.

I believe this was discussed before, in #q204631 for instance. That Q&A also contains some links to tools that can strip them out and also mentions `less` that should be able to show the contents including ANSI colours.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1